# How can we get the data from map in a spinner when we select the city and internally select the value of that filed

Tags: java, android, json, collections, spinner

When we select the spinner the internally we use the id in this spinner

```
stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(int i=0; i<createdtrs_array.length(); i++)
{   
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("id", createdtrs_array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));                            
    map.put("name", createdtrs_array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
    myList.add(map);

    stringArray.add(createdtrs_array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BusTickets.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
destnation.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: PLs try to explain exactly what you want/need and where you have a problem.

Comment: Dear Sir thanks for interested in my question ..Actually i need when we select the spinner i can get the id of that selection of name

Comment: try this ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>(BusTickets.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
destnation.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: thanks Mr Dhiraj kumar ji  But i already try this but this give all data in spinner

Comment: Hello Pphoenix,and Mr Th Minion  Dear have you understand my Question now ..